# Skip GraphQL Resolvers to return data

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I have a GraphQl resolvers that resolves nested data.

for eg. this is my type definitions

```
type Users {
  _id: String
  company: Company
}
```

For the post I have my resolver which resolves post._id as

```
Users: {
  company: (instance, arguments, context, info) => {
   return instance.company && Company.find({_id: instance.company});
  }
}
```

The above example works perfectly fine when I query for

```
Query {
 Users {
  _id
  name
  username
  company {
    _id
    PAN
    address
  }
 }
}
```

But the problem is sometime I don't have to use the `company` resolver inside `Users`, because it is coming along with the user so I just need to pass what's in the user object (no need of database call here)

I can achieve this just by checking if instance.company is and _id or `Object`, if `_id` get from database otherwise resolve whatever coming in.

But the problem is I have these type of resolvers in many places so I don't think it's a good idea to have this check in all places wherever I have resolver.

Is there a better way where I can define a configuration just to skip this resolver check.

Any feedback or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you find a solution for this in the meantime?